# How to make my UIPickerView display all elements of an array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView and an array though I can't seem to be able to input all the date from the array into the UIPicker.

I know that the syntax is meant to be like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return [treatments objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Where treatments is the array name though when I use this it comes up with this error:

```
-[Treatment isEqualToString:]: unrecognized
```

I have searched my entire project and can't find the phrase: `isEqualToString`

Treatment.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Treatment : NSObject {
    NSString *treatmentid;
    NSString *treatmentName;
    NSString *treatmentPrice;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *treatmentid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *treatmentName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *treatmentPrice;

@end
```

All picker codes:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [treatments count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [treatments objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

If you need any more code just say

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove your app. from simulator and clean your project and just run again.

Comment: How would I do that???

Comment: I am quite new to this stuff so go easy

Comment: in your simulator, hold down app's icon and delete ur apps. and go to xcode project and "Product" manu and select "Clean".. and run your app

Comment: Hmm. @iPatel still the same issue

Comment: is it possibly because there are multiple items in each array type. So name price

Comment: just past my given code into your project and see the NSLog if in your array there is NSDictionary then you must specify with NSdictionar and it's Key

Comment: post your full picker delegate code and about `treatments`...

Comment: may be you need to return your array with key like this return[[treatments objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"YourKey"]; check edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you your Array contain Dictionar or NSMutableDictionar then you must specify value of array with it's key like bellow try to writtern you method like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return[[treatments objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"YourKey"];
}
```

Here is basic Implementation of  Picker view sample example code:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thepickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thepickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return [treatments count];
}
```

customize displaying lable of UIpickerview like bellow:-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];



        if (component == 0) {

            label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
            label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];

             NSLog(@"%@",[yourpickerview selectedRowInComponent:component]);

        }

    return label;

}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

   NSLog(@"%@",[treatments objectAtIndex:row]);

}
```

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you another question that has just cropped up

Comment: say i m trying to give u solution